# Marshall array of structures C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a problem with marshalling. I tried to translate C++ structs to C# but it doesn't work.

**C# code**

```
namespace DLL_IMPORT_TEST
{
    public struct CUDA_POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public CUDA_POINT(int X, int Y)
        {
            x = X;
            y = Y;
        }
    }

    public struct DataStruct
    {
        public Int64 a;
        public long b;
        public long c;
        public CUDA_POINT d;

        public DataStruct(int p1, int p2, long p3, CUDA_POINT p4)
        {
            a = p1;
            b = p2;
            c = p3;
            d = new CUDA_POINT(p4.x, p4.y);
        }
    }   


    [DllImport("DLL_C++.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    unsafe public static extern void PrintDataStruct(ref DataStruct d1);

    private void OnPrintBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataStruct d1 = new DataStruct(1000, 1000, -10, new CUDA_POINT(0,0));
        string s1 = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}, {4}\n", d1.a, d1.b, d1.c, d1.d.x, d1.d.y);
        PrintDataStruct(ref d1);
        PrintBox.Text += s1;
    }        
}
```

**C++ code**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void PrintDataStruct(DataStruct d1){
    ofstream outFile("Output.txt");
    outFile << "a == " << d1.a << endl;
    outFile << "b == " << d1.b << endl;
    outFile << "c == " << d1.c << endl;
    outFile << "d == " << d1.d.x << ", " << d1.d.y << endl;
    outFile.close();
}
```

The output of C# is correct, but the output of C++ is incorrect.

**C# output**

```
1000
1000
-10
0,0
```

**C++ output**

```
1000
1000
-10
-10, -1
```

Comment: try adding [`[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to your struct definition

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what this question is about. particularly this line "*The output of C # is correct, But the output of c ++ is garbage*"

Comment: What does the struct look like on the C++ side?

Comment: Struct on the C++

typedef struct tagCUDA_POINT
{
 int x;
 int y;
} CUDA_POINT;

typedef struct DataStruct
{
 __int64 a;
 unsigned long b;
 signed long c;
 CUDA_POINT d;
}DataStruct;

Comment: Input on C#
"DataStruct d1 = new DataStruct(1000, 1000, -10, new CUDA_POINT(0,0));"

But 

Output on C#
1000, 100, -10, (0,0)

Output on C++
100, 100, -10, (-10,-10)